# Prove that for each submodule $B$, there exist a submodule $C$ such that $A=B\oplus C$.

Tags: modules, direct-sum, division-ring

Problem: Let $A$ be a unitary module over a division ring $R$. Prove that for each submodule $B$, there exist a submodule $C$ such that $A=B\oplus C$.

Anyone can help me in this problem? I really don't see the connection between the premises and the conclusion. I don't even know where to start, I mean I can start with the premises but it is just until there I don't know where to proceed. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Well, presumably you do see the connection if we added the assumption that the ring is commutative?

Comment: It says only that R is a division ring, not commutative. How should I do this?

Comment: Did you check where the proof for the commutative case breaks down if you try to repeat it?

Comment: I'm sorry but I also don't know the proof for that case either. :(

Comment: @FlickerBeat Do you know any basic linear algebra?

Answer (score 1):

Note that every unitary module A over a division ring R has a basis (and therefore
a free R-module).Existence of basis implies A is the internal direct sum of cyclic
submodules based on the equivalent conditions in the definition of free module. If
you can show that every submodule B of A is cyclic and is among the cyclic submodule
mentioned above then I think that proves it. Our choice of C will be the internal
direct sum of the remaining cyclic submodules. 
This is just my take on the matter, I haven't fully researched on this yet. Hope
this helps.

Comment: Is this true for all bases? Like if the basis is finite or infinite?

Comment: Can you give me more about submodules being cyclic? I have searching it but I couldn't show it, only submodules of the form Ra are cyclic.